# Excel Formula For Current Row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a working formula which specifies the current row number:

```
=IF(AND(Part_Qty>0, COUNTA(Parts!Z15:AI15)>0),"GROUP NAME TEMP L "," ")
```

I'm trying to convert the formula so that I am using the Row function but I cant see to get it to work properly.

```
=IF(AND(Part_Qty>0, COUNTA(INDIRECT("Parts!Z"&ROW()):INDIRECT("Parts!AI"&ROW())>0)),"GROUP NAME TEMP L "," ")
```

Hoping someone can help me out here.

Thanks

Comment: We can get `INDIRECT()` to work, but that would be volatile. Using on many rows might hit processing time. Therefor try: `=IF(AND(Part_Qty>0,COUNTA(INDEX(Parts!Z:Z,ROW()):INDEX(Parts!AI:AI,ROW()))>0),"GROUP NAME TEMP L "," ")`.

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you very much.